# NoMethodError error for search_methods activeadmin

Tags: activeadmin

I am trying to create customised filters for a resource. I have used search_methods to declare the filter and have defined it in a scope. But I am getting a NoMethodError for search_methods.
Is there a gem for this or am I missing out something?

Comment: I am using activeadmin 1.0.0.pre4 and rails 5

Answer (score 0):

`search_methods` is method from the `meta_search` gem, ActiveAdmin 1.x don't work with this gem anymore. Take a look on the `ransack` gem and move your code to it.